# react-navigation StackNavigator + Redux, back button shows previous screen with old props

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

https://vid.me/SYMi

**Expected behaviour**

1. addBookmark action gets triggered
2. Back button clicked
3. Redux updates VendorsGallery which is in a react-navigation StackNavigator, just below a VendorsFullGallery

VendorGallery gets new props correctly, this is correctly console-logged from the componentWillMount() method.

This lifecycle event gets triggered correctly when I edit bookmarks in the VendorsFullScreenGallery. In general, Redux seems to be hooked correctly, in fact by switching VendorGallery's sub-tab I get to see the new props.

Seems like react-navigation is forcing the 'previous' component to show with the props it originally had.

Any ideas?

Code for Gallery:

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    bookmarks: state.Bookmarks,
    products: state.Products
  }
}

class Gallery extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    /* Comes from Router */
    this.data = {
      initialTag: this.props.navigation.state.params.initialTag,
      hasFilters: this.props.navigation.state.params.hasFilters
    }

    if (this.data.hasFilters) {
      activeGalleryTags = new Set();
      if (this.data.initialTag)
        activeGalleryTags.add(this.data.initialTag)

      this.state = {
        currentTab: this.data.initialTag ? 1 : 0,
        activeGalleryTags: activeGalleryTags
      }

      console.debug(this.props.navigation);
    }
    else 
      this.state = { 
        currentTab: 0
      }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    console.log("Did mount");
  }

  componentWillUpdate () {
    console.log("Will update");
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    console.log("Will receive props");
    console.debug(nextProps);
  }

  _checkBookmark (product) {
    if (this.props.bookmarks !== {}) {
      console.debug("Checking bookmark");
      for (id in this.props.bookmarks)
        if (this.props.bookmarks[id].res_id == product.id) {
          console.debug("Ok", product.id);
          return id;
        }

        return null;
    }
  }

  /* Callback for <TagList>, _newState is TagList's internal collection of selected tags */
  _onTagClicked (_newState) {
    this.setState({
      activeGalleryTags: _newState
    })
  }

  _onZoomClicked (id) {
    params_ = {
      selectedID: id
    }

    this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: 'VendorFullGallery',
        params: params_
      })
    )
  }

  _renderFeaturedGallery () {
    gallery = new Array();
    thumbWrapper = {
      width: Dimensions.get('window').width/1.3 - 12, 
      height: Dimensions.get('window').height/1.6 - 12,
      margin: 5
    };

    this.props.products.productsList
      .filter(
        (p) => {
          return p.featured
        }
      )
      .map((p) => {
        gallery.push(
          <PictureThumb 
          onZoomClicked={this._onZoomClicked.bind(this, p.id)} 
          key={p.id} 
          product={p} 
          wrapperStyle={thumbWrapper}
          bookmarkID={this._checkBookmark(p)}
          />
        );
      });

      return gallery;
    }

    _renderGallery () {
      gallery = new Array();

      thumbWrapper = {
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width/2 - 15, 
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height/3 - 12, 
        margin: 5
      };

      if (this.data.hasFilters && this.state.activeGalleryTags.size > 0)
        filteredProducts = this.props.products.productsList.filter((p) => this.state.activeGalleryTags.has(p.category))
      else
        filteredProducts = this.props.products.productsList;

      filteredProducts.map(
          (p) => {
            gallery.push(
              <PictureThumb 
                key={p.id} 
                bookmarkID={this._checkBookmark(p)}
                onZoomClicked={this._onZoomClicked.bind(this, p.id)} 
                product={p} 
                wrapperStyle={thumbWrapper} 
                />
            );
          }
        );

      return gallery;
    }


  _showAllProducts () {
    return (
      <View>
        <TagList tags={this.props.products.tags} initialTag={this.data.initialTag} behaveAsFilter={true} onTagClicked={this._onTagClicked.bind(this)} />
        <ScrollView>
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              {this._renderGallery()}
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }

  _showFeatured () {
    return (
      <Coverflow perspective={900} wingSpan={10} style={{marginTop: 20}} onChange={(index) => {}}>
        {this._renderFeaturedGallery()}
      </Coverflow>
    )
  }

  render () {
    console.log("Rerender gallery");

    let show = null;
    switch (this.state.currentTab) {
      case 0:
        show = this._showFeatured()
        break;
      case 1:
        show = this._showAllProducts();
        break;
    }

    return(
      <View style={globalStyles.wrapper}>
        <View style={{width: 300, margin: 10, alignSelf: 'center'}}>
          <SegmentedControlTab 
            values={['FEATURED', 'ALL PRODUCTS']} 
            selectedIndex={this.state.currentTab} 
            onTabPress={index => this.setState({currentTab:index})}
            tabStyle={{
              borderColor: globalStyles.NAVIMODA_BLUE
            }}
            tabTextStyle={{
              fontSize: 10,
              letterSpacing: 1
            }}
            activeTabStyle={{
              backgroundColor: globalStyles.NAVIMODA_BLUE
            }}
            activeTabTextStyle={{
              color: 'white'
            }}
            />
        </View>
        <View>
          {show}
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Gallery);
```

Code for FullScreenGallery:

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {
        bookmarks: state.Bookmarks,
        products: state.Products
    }
}

class FullScreenGallery extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        tabBarVisible: false
    };

    constructor (props) {
        super (props);

        this.data = {
            selectedIndex: this.props.navigation.state.params.selectedID
        }

        this.data.selectedIndex = this.props.products.productsList.findIndex((p) => { 
            return p.id == this.props.navigation.state.params.selectedID 
        });

        this.state = {
            visibleSwiper: false
        }
    }

    _checkBookmark (product) {
        if (this.props.bookmarks !== {}) {
            console.debug("Checking bookmark");
            for (id in this.props.bookmarks)
                if (this.props.bookmarks[id].res_id == product.id) {
                console.debug("Ok", product.id);
                return id;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({visibleSwiper: true})
        }, 100);

        this.props.navigation.dispatch(
            NavigationActions.setParams({
                params: { hideTabBar: true },
                key: 'Index',
            })
        );
    }

    onShowVendorClicked () {    
        if (this.props.products.vendor !== null)
            this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({
                routeName: 'VendorDetail'
            }))

    }

    _renderPics () {
        let _pics = new Array();

        this.props.products.productsList.map((p) => {
        if (this.data.vendor) {
            _pics.push(
                <PictureDetail 
                key={p.id} 
                product={p} 
                onShowVendorClicked={this.onShowVendorClicked.bind(this)} 
                vendor={this.props.product.vendor} 
                bookmarkID={this._checkBookmark(p)}
                />
            )
        }
        else
            _pics.push(
                <PictureDetail 
                key={p.id} 
                product={p} 
                onShowVendorClicked={this.onShowVendorClicked.bind(this)} 
                vendor={p.vendor} 
                bookmarkID={this._checkBookmark(p)}
                />
            )
        });

        return _pics;
    }

    render () {
        if (this.state.visibleSwiper)
            return (
                <Swiper index={this.data.selectedIndex}>
                    {this._renderPics()}
                </Swiper>
            )
        else 
            return (
                <View style={globalStyles.spinnerWrapper}>
                    <Spinner color='black' />
                </View>
                )
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FullScreenGallery)
```

Comment: Do you have some code to share? I do believe it is going to be difficult to help you without taking a look at the code.

Comment: I guess you're right!